# Android : collect Quick Search Box result form internet

Tags: android, search-box

I'm doing a app which allow user to search on the server. how can i get the text from the Quick Search Box and send to server?

```
if (Intent.ACTION_SEARCH.equals(intent.getAction())) {

     String search= intent.getStringExtra(SearchManager.QUERY);
}
```

the string "search" is it the text which typing by user?

P/S: sorry about my bad english. Hope you guys understand what's I'm talking about.
Thanks.

Regard

Wynix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the String "search" is the string the user has searched for.

Once you have this you can send a request to your server using an HttpGet-object:

```
HttpGet get = new HttpGet("http://yourserver.com" + search);
HttpResponse response = null;
try {
  response = client.execute(get);
}
catch (IOException e) {}
catch (ClientProtocolException e) {}
```

Then you can parse the result from the HttpResponse-object:

```
String result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
```

Comment: Thanks for reply. problem fix!